# Why does docker stop immediately after starting and how to prevent it from stopping?

Tags: post, docker

I am trying to start a docker container using the following POST request:

```
  Content-Type: application/json
{
         "Hostname":"",
         "Domainname": "",
         "User":"",
         "Memory":0,
         "MemorySwap":0,
         "CpuShares": 512,
         "Cpuset": "0,1",
         "AttachStdin":true,
         "AttachStdout":true,
         "AttachStderr":true,
         "PortSpecs":6002,
         "Tty":false,
         "OpenStdin":false,
         "StdinOnce":false,
         "Env":null,
         "Cmd":
       [
           "python",
           "app.py"
       ],
         "Image":"jobinar/smile_webapp",
         "Volumes":{
                 "/tmp": {}
         },
         "WorkingDir":"",
         "NetworkDisabled": false,
         "ExposedPorts":{
                 "5000/tcp": {}
         }
    }
```

However, the container immediately stops after starting. How do I configure my request to prevent it from exiting?

I would appreciate a POST request which does this instead of the command-line way.

**EDIT:** I get a 201 CREATED response with the id of the created container and I can see that the container is created by running by using the `docker ps -a` command.

Comment: is "python app.py" starting a service in the background and returning immediately. If so it would have this effect

Comment: Check the logs using ```docker logs CONTAINERID```. Your app my by exiting prematurely.

Comment: @ArthurUlfeldt: It runs in the foreground and runs without issues when started from the command-line.

Comment: Which http request are you using?  e.g. POST /containers/create will only create the container; you then need to POST /containers/(id)/start

Answer (score 0):

If you have upgraded you docker version you habe to delete `/var/lib/docker/network` on *ubuntu*